# Can't select forms in Firefox?

Tags: css, forms, firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/gBG65/4/

In emulation of my actual project, here we have a text input within a div. The div and everything else in it *must be unselectable*, hence its CSS. **But the form ought not to be that way, hence its CSS,** yet it is anyway. Even though if I inspect the element, it inherited everything correctly and ought to be working, it is still unselectable.

This is Firefox only.

Any explanations or fixes?

```
div * {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    cursor:default;
}

input {
    cursor: auto;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-user-select:text;
}
```

Comment: "must be" unselectable - be aware that users can edit this property to make elements selectable if they like

Comment: Oh, yes, I know that. I didn't mean it **MUST** be unselectable, just that it ought to be for optimal user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-user-select)

You can see it is `-moz-none;`

And to re-enable use: `-moz-user-select: text;`

Also remove the `*`...

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gBG65/)

Comment: Silly silly me, trusting SO...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: If you just looked 1 answer further ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting#4358620

Comment: Waiiiiiiit a minute. You took out the asterisk. If I put it back, it stops working again. I need that asterisk to make all the div's other children unselectable. Why is that asterisk overriding the element's style?

Comment: "Starting with Firefox 21 none behaves like -moz-none."

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was strange too, that `none` nevertheless does not work. So *really*, the docs are not helpful here.

Comment: @Aerovistae current stable firefox is 20.0.1, so `none` "will" work fine soon, but not yet for most FFX users